# Intersection of $L$-structures, substructures

Tags: logic, model-theory

The task is to show that the intersection of substructures is a substructure (or empty). Disclaimer: I think it is enough to answer the question in the last orange box, to answer my question... The post got a little longer, but most of the stuff is context and own thoughts. So you do not have to read everything, if you are familiar with the topic.

Definition (substructure):

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language and $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ two $\mathcal{L}$-structures. We say that $\mathcal{B}$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{A}$ if the following holds:
>
> a) $B\subseteq A$
>
> b) For every constant symbol $c\in\mathcal{L}$ is $c^{\mathcal{A}}=c^{\mathcal{B}}$
>
> c) For every n-digit function symbol $f\in\mathcal{L}$ is $f^\mathcal{B}=f^\mathcal{A}|\mathcal{B}^n$ (the restriction of $f^{\mathcal{A}}$ on $\mathcal{B}^n$) and $\mathcal{B}$ is closed with regards to $f^{\mathcal{B}}$
>
> d) For every m-digit relation symbol $R\in\mathcal{L}$ is $R^\mathcal{A}\cap\mathcal{B}^m=R^\mathcal{B}$

So let $L$ be a language, $\mathcal{A}=(A, (z^\mathcal{A})_{z\in L}$ a L-structure, $I$ a set of indices and $\mathcal{A}_i=(A_i, (z^{\mathcal{A}_i})_{z\in L})$ a familiy of substructures of $\mathcal{A}$.

I have to show, that $\mathcal{S}=\bigcap_{i\in I}\mathcal{A}_i$ ('shortend definition' see 'at b)') is a substructure of $\mathcal{A}$, or empty.

Suppose $S\neq\emptyset$.

a): $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i\subseteq A$ holds true, since $A_i\subseteq A$ for every $i\in I$.

But now I start to struggle with the formalism, I guess.

at b): For every constant $c\in L$ is $c^{\mathcal{A}}=c^{\mathcal{A}_i}$ for every $i\in I$, because $\mathcal{A}_i$ is a substructure of $\mathcal{A}$.

I have to show, that the interpretation of $c$ in $\mathcal{S}$ is the same as in $\mathcal{A}$. Or in other words $c^\mathcal{A}=c^\mathcal{S}$.

> How are the constants symbols in $\mathcal{S}$ 'generated'?

Every L-structure has a set of constants symbols. These do not have to be necessarly equal. Here they are, because we are intersecting substructures of $\mathcal{A}$.
Obviously we simply intersect these sets of constant symbols. [Or relation and function symbols]
But how is that formalised?

> Do we write simply $\mathcal{S}=(\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i, \bigcap_{i\in I} (z^\mathcal{A_i})_{z\in L})$?

What I find confusing is what we really intersect here?
So can we even make sense out of $\bigcap_{i\in I} (z^\mathcal{A_i})_{i\in I}$. That is if $(z^\mathcal{A_i})_{i\in I}$ is a set (of constant, function and relation symbols) and not, as the notation lets you suspect, a tupel...

So basically (as one would suspect...) $c^\mathcal{S}=c^\mathcal{A}\Leftrightarrow c^{\mathcal{A}_i}=c^\mathcal{A}$ for every $i\in I$.

Thanks in advance.
I will add c), and d) later as this got longer as planned already.

---

Example: Take a language $L=(0,1,+)$ with the usual interpretations. Now I write down L-structures, where $A,B\subseteq\mathbb{N}$:

$\mathcal{N}=(\mathbb{N},0^\mathcal{N},1^\mathcal{N},+^\mathcal{N})$ (with the usual interpretation)

$\mathcal{A}=(A,0^\mathcal{A},1^\mathcal{A},+^\mathcal{A})$. Where $0^\mathcal{A}=0$, $1^\mathcal{A}=1$ and $+^\mathcal{A}$ is still the usual addition.

Now I take $\mathcal{B}=(B,0^\mathcal{B},1^\mathcal{B},+^\mathcal{B})$, where $+^\mathcal{B}$ still notes the usual addition, but we swap

$1^\mathcal{B}=0$ and $0^\mathcal{B}=1$

Then $\mathcal{B}$ is not a substructure of $N$? Because for $0\in L$ we do not have $0^\mathbb{N}=0^\mathcal{B}$

---

Comment: I like this definition of a substructure. What is the original source?

Comment: @GregNisbet Thank you for your comment. Actually I can not remember, but is this not the common definition? It should be of the lecture notes I had, so I can not give a specific reference. Sorry. German courses on an Introduction to Logic normally follow the notes by Martin Ziegler.

Comment: It is the common definition from what I can tell, but Marker (the textbook I'm reading) defines it by saying that the inclusion map must be an embedding in a remark in the introduction that's hard to find. I just meant that I like the form of the definition in your question. (Earlier today I couldn't remember whether a superstructure is allowed to make interpretations of relation symbols "truer" or not)

Comment: Yes, I think the stated definition is just more detailed, as an inclusion map means just that, when you interpret it in the context of L-structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will refer to the interpretations of the constant, function and relation symbols in $\mathcal A$ as “the constants, functions and relations.”

A subset $B\subseteq A$ forms a substructure if and only if it is closed under all of the functions and contains all of the constants. Then it makes sense to interpret the constant symbols in $\mathcal B$ as the respective constants and the function symbols as the restrictions of the respective functions. (Restricting the relation always makes sense.)

So you just need to show that the intersection of sets closed under a set of functions is also closed. (And it’s trivial that the intersection of sets that contain some given constants also contains those constants.)

A note on the part about empty/non-empty. Whether to allow empty structures is one of those annoying things where sometimes it is natural and sometimes it isn’t, so the convention of not allowing them can sometimes cause unnecessary complications. Here it is more natural just to let trivial cases be trivial: after all, the empty set is closed under any set of functions. Notice also, if there are any constant symbols that the intersection will not be empty.

Comment: Do you mind commenting on my proposed thoughts. I know that it is trivial that it is trivial that the intersection of sets also contains those constants. What I am struggeling with is the formalisation and abstraction going into this.

Comment: Regarding your last note, yes if you assign the constant symbols something different, it is no longer a substructure. It’s also not clear that $A$ can be a substructure since it’s not clear that “the usual +” is a function on $A$... this is why closure is important. (This is just a generalization of, say, the notion of a subgroup, if that’s more familiar.)

Comment: Regarding the other part, you are taking the concept of an intersection much too literally. I would hope you know what is meant when we say an intersection of subgroups “is a subgroup”. Or more generally that a given subset “is a subgroup”. For instance, “the even integers are a subgroup of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ whereas the odd integers are not” makes sense, right? It’s exactly analogous for substructures.

Comment: It also appears you are mixing in the syntax somehow, talking about what constant symbols the substructure “has”. This is a mixup: the signature / language (i.e. what symbols there are) is fixed... both the structure and the substructure are structures of the same signature. The issue is what to assign to the symbols. You seem to implicitly understand this in your last example though.

Comment: This is important: for example the even integers are a substructure of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ but not of $(\mathbb Z, +, 1).$

Comment: Thank you very much! Your example with the 'subgroup' is enlighting. Didnt come to my mind. As I said, I think the abstractation and formalism is holding me back here. Your comments helped alot. I will think about the task now (espacially your answer, which is not 100% clear to me at the moment), and probably ask again. Also I would like to really prove every part 'by definition'.

Comment: I think the problem with “by definition” is that there is really no prior definition of the intersection as a structure, since it’s not clear at the outset that the intersection of the domains can support proper interpretation the symbols in a natural way - this is what we are trying to show. I promise it is infinitely better to think about things in the way I’ve outlined. If you like, first define the substructure generated by a subset, and then the question becomes to show the substructure generated by the intersection has as its domain the intersection (ie nothing else needs to be added.)